# Javascript - help debug simple game?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple game where there are two doors, one containing the prize, the other does not (randomly generated). The user can click on either, and be notified if they won/lost. When I run the following code, the result is always "Boo you lose". I suspect it has something to do with:

```
if ("door1Selection" === "randomDoor"){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let doors = ["door1", "door2"]

  function selectDoor() {
    const randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
    return randomDoor
  }

  const $door1 = $('.door1')
  const $door2 = $('.door2')

  $door1.click(function() {
    const door1Selection = $door1.attr('class');
    if ("door1Selection" === "randomDoor") {
      alert("Yay you win")
    } else {
      alert("Boo you lose")
    }
  })

  $door2.click(function() {
    var door2Selection = $door2.attr('class');
    if ("door2Selection" === "randomDoor") {
      alert("Yay you win")
    } else {
      alert("Boo you lose")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="door1">button 1</button>
<button class="door2">button 2</button>
```

Comment: You are testing against different strings not different variables, also your `randomDoor` variable is not in a visible scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're comparing literal string rather than variables.
- You need to call the function `selectDoor()` to get the random index.  The variable `randomDoor` scope is closed to selectDoor's block.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let doors = ["door1", "door2"]

  function selectDoor() {
    const randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
    return randomDoor
  }

  const $door1 = $('.door1')
  const $door2 = $('.door2')

  $door1.click(function() {
    const door1Selection = $door1.attr('class');
    if (door1Selection === selectDoor()) {
      alert("Yay you win")
    } else {
      alert("Boo you lose")
    }
  })

  $door2.click(function() {
    var door2Selection = $door2.attr('class');
    if (door2Selection === selectDoor()) {
      alert("Yay you win")
    } else {
      alert("Boo you lose")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="door1">button 1</button>
<button class="door2">button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should not be wrapped in quotation marks. That makes it a string, so you are comparing the strings `door2Selection === randomDoor` which will never be true.

You want:

```
if (door1Selection === randomDoor)
```

and

```
if (door2Selection === randomDoor)
```

You also need to pull the declaration of `randomDoor` out of the function. Put it with your `doors` declaration (and make it a `let`):

```
let doors = [ /* stuff */ ];
let randomDoor;

function selectDoor() {
  randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
  return randomDoor;
}
```

Comment: When I remove quotation marks on both, I get the error that randomDoor is undefined

Comment: @ChiLee That is because it is declared in the function so once the function ends it doesnt exist.

Comment: That approach is ugly, the OP just needs to call that function.

Comment: It depends if they want to initialize the random door at the start of the game or pick it when the door is picked. That's a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Variables should not be placed in quotes when they are compared. When you put them in quotes, you are comparing the variable names themselves not the values of the variables.

```
if ("door1Selection" === "randomDoor"){
```

should be

```
if (door1Selection === randomDoor) {
```

However, there are several areas where this could use improvement:

- The variable randomDoor is created as a const within the selectDoor method, but it goes out of scope when the function returns its value so it cannot be use for comparison later. Therefore, you should set the randomDoor variable outside of the function completely or just get rid of it and call selectDoor in the if statement.
- You can easily merge the click event methods to one click even on all buttons with a class of door.

Making these changes results in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let doors = ["door1", "door2"]

    function selectDoor() {
        return doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
    }

    $('.door').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(selectDoor())) {
            alert("Yay you win")
        } else {
            alert("Boo you lose")
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="door door1">Door 1</button>
<button class="door door2">Door 2</button>
```